Start screen lock for user from systemd
This is a script to start a screen lock in Ubuntu, with user customizable background image(s).
The script will eventually be run on sleep by systemd, so by root. This made it complicated to let the user customize the directory of the images to choose from. I ended up (with the help of a well-known LLM) using a config file (~/.config/xsecurelock.env) to set an environment variable.
The config may contain ~, $HOME, ... To expand these, the script reads the file line by line, with sudo -u "$ACTIVE_USER" bash -c "echo $line".
The whole thing works, but feels quite cumbersome, so I came here to ask it there would be a more canonical way to do this.
I considered using bash -l to get all user variables, which would remove the need for ~/.config/xsecurelock.env, but started a whole login shell seemed inappropriately much.
#!/bin/bash
### # xsecurelock built from source, had to fix and sent a PR:
### # https://github.com/google/xsecurelock/pull/176

# Get the active session ID and user for the currently logged-in graphical session
SESSION_ID=$(loginctl list-sessions | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1; exit}')
ACTIVE_USER=$(loginctl show-session "$SESSION_ID" -p Name --value)

# If no session or user is found, exit early
if [ -z "$SESSION_ID" ] || [ -z "$ACTIVE_USER" ]; then
    echo "No active session or user found"
    exit 1
fi

ACTIVE_USER_HOME=$(eval echo "~$ACTIVE_USER")
ENV_FILE="$ACTIVE_USER_HOME/.config/xsecurelock.env"

# If the environment file doesn't exist, exit early
if [ ! -f "$ENV_FILE" ]; then
    echo "Environment file $ENV_FILE not found"
    exit 1
fi

# Read the file, even the last line if lacking a newline
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    # Expand ~ and $HOME in the environment file before export
    expanded_line=$(sudo -u "$ACTIVE_USER" bash -c "echo $line")
    eval "$expanded_line"
done < "$ENV_FILE"

# Read XSECURELOCK_SAVER_IMAGE_DIR from the user's ~/.config/xsecurelock.env.
# Do not revert to a default location of images, no surprises.

# Pick a random image
XSECURELOCK_SAVER_IMAGE=$(find "$XSECURELOCK_SAVER_IMAGE_DIR" -type f | sort -R | head -1)

# The actual lock screen command
XSECURELOCK_SAVER_IMAGE=${XSECURELOCK_SAVER_IMAGE} XSECURELOCK_SAVER=/usr/local/bin/lock-with-image-photo-saver xsecurelock

All comments welcome, on style, safety, elegant alternatives.

The script is run by root, and does eval?

Got you, thanks. I just replaced it with export, for another reason. I have a feeling that this is overly complicated anyway, is there an easier, safer way to load the current user's variables?

I wouldn't touch this with a barge-pole:

while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    # Expand ~ and $HOME in the environment file before export
    expanded_line=$(sudo -u "$ACTIVE_USER" bash -c "echo $line")
    eval "$expanded_line"
done < "$ENV_FILE"


It seems that a malicious user could easily write 'chmod u+s /bin/sh' (or something more subtle) into the file that's under their control.
It's probably best to become the desired user as quickly as possible once that's determined, rather than continuing to run all this dangerous stuff as root.

Right, I see that now. "become the desired user", so you mean something like bash -l? Or su?

bash -l doesn't change user - you'll need something like runuser -l -u "$ACTIVE_USER" start-screen-lock-user.

That's the thing, I haven't found how to run a command in that session. For example right now, I have two sessions with the same user, I want to call the screenlock for the session that is up, right now. I think I can achieve finding the session ID with loginctl, but running in that session, I don't know.

I don't know much about systemd sessions, but I'd guess that becoming port of a session might just be a matter of copying the environment variables from the session leader (i.e. from /proc/$PID/environ) into this process.

I meant part of a session, not "port" - sorry for any confusion.


Don't use all upper-case names for non-exported variables, see correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization.
Don't store commands like XSECURELOCK_SAVER=/usr/local/bin/lock-with-image-photo-saver ... in scalar variables, see Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables!.
Setting a variable at the start of the line XSECURELOCK_SAVER_IMAGE=${XSECURELOCK_SAVER_IMAGE} XSECURELOCK_SAVER=/usr/local/bin/lock-with-image-photo-saver xsecurelock would only make sense if you were trying to execute /usr/local/bin/lock-with-image-photo-saver xsecurelock on that line but then you'd need $(/usr/local/bin/lock-with-image-photo-saver xsecurelock) or similar.
Whatever you're trying to do with ACTIVE_USER_HOME=$(eval echo "~$ACTIVE_USER"), there's a better way. Maybe something like ACTIVE_USER_HOME=$(getent passwd "$ACTIVE_USER" | cut -d: -f6) or a ACTIVE_USER_HOME=$(bash -c "cd ~$(printf '%q' "$ACTIVE_USER") && pwd") or similar.
Don't do eval "$expanded_line" without first validating that "$expanded_line" contains the type of code you expect it to contain and is safe to eval. It's not obvious why you'd need to do this at all though.
Use [[ ... ]] instead of [ ... ], see are-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-bash.
Use #!/usr/bin/env bash instead of #!/bin/bash, see what-is-the-difference-between-usr-bin-env-bash-and-usr-bin-bash.
Direct error or status messages to stderr instead of stdout, e.g. echo "No active session or user found" >&2.

